# Metadata Manager for MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, metadata

We are using MapInfo in our organisation to maintain corporate GIS datasets (in TAB files). We've come to realise the importance of maintaining a metadata file for our GIS layers. Are there any free/open-source metadata managers out there that can help us achieve the desired objectives?

Answer (score 0):

[**GIS Metadata Manager**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gis-manager/) is an open source project.

You may also want to have a look at:
[**Esri Geoportal Server**](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal).

Answer (score 0):

TAB files has included meta data for quite some years now. Either look inside the TAB file with a text editor or use the tool "Table Manager", which can also edit/view the meta data.